# How to loop through the dataframe after droping some rows from the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, sentiment-analysis

I have a dataframe from which i have deleted some rows. But the problem i have been facing is when i try to loop through dataframe on the basis of index values it gives me 'key error!' due to some indices are missing from the dataframe. How to loop through the dataframe?

```
dataset =pd.read_csv('sentimentAnalysis.csv') # dataset imported
dataset = dataset[dataset['reviews.rating']!=3] #dropped the rows which 
                                                 contain ratings =3
for i in range[0,5000]:    #encounter error at i = 222 cause that row is missing due to the previous line of code
    #XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: You have to reset your index after filtering: `dataset = dataset[dataset['reviews.rating']!=3].reset_index()`

Comment: `for i in range(len(df)):... df.iloc[i]`

Comment: @QuangHoang If you can avoid it, try not to iterate like `for i in range(len(df)):  …df.iloc[i]`, its terribly slow, [see here](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) for an explanation why.

Comment: @Asmus agreed. But that’s not me to say. I was just trying to correct op’s code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41022840/8363478 this may help you

Comment: @Erfan Should that comment be an answer? Seems like you could already have got 4 upvotes :-)

Comment: Added it as answer. Thanks for the heads up @DarrenCook :). Probably wont get the upvotes anymore though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reset your index after filtering:

```
dataset = dataset[dataset['reviews.rating']!=3].reset_index()
```